# Why the substraction of two big numbers does not yield 0, but taking their quotient yields 1?

Tags: numerics, numerical-value, numeric-array

I have two series, generated as,

```
dFO[n_] := (Gamma[1 + n, 2 I \[Pi]] - Gamma[1 + n, -2 I \[Pi]])/(
 2^(2 + n) I \[Pi] n)
dCI[n_] := -(Gamma[n]/2^n)
t[n_, k_] := -(((I \[Pi])^(k - n) Gamma[k])/(
   Gamma[k - n + 1] Gamma[n])) (2 - 2^(k - n)) BernoulliB[k - n]

Data1[NN_] := Table[dCI[n] // N // Chop, {n, 1, NN}]
Data2[NN_] := 
 Table[Sum[dFO[k] t[k, n], {k, 1, n}] // N // Chop, {n, 1, NN}]
```

When printed numerically on screen, the two series are seen to be similar but not equal. To quantify the discrepancy I can either substract the series or take their quotient, but this yields

```
In[280]:= Data1[20] - Data2[20]

Out[280]= {-5.55112*10^-17, -1.38778*10^-16, 2.22045*10^-16, -4.44089*10^-16, 8.88178*10^-16, 8.88178*10^-15, -8.52651*10^-14, 1.25056*10^-12, -2.95586*10^-11, 2.18279*10^-11, -1.07684*10^-9, 
 1.02445*10^-8, -9.73232*10^-8, 1.92598*10^-6, -0.0000576973, 0.0000925064, -0.00834465, 0.140152, 
-1.39063, 40.2266}

Data1[20]/Data2[20]

Out[279]= {1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., \
1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.}
```

so according to the substraction some entries are clearly different but still the quotient is always 1.

I imagine this is an issue of working with numerical values, and I can understand that if two numbers satisfy that x-y is of order 10^(-15) their quotient can be returned as 1. But for other entries of the series the substraction is of order 1, 10, 100 and higher, so I can't see why all the quotients are 1.

P.S.1) I am working under the assumption that the substraction and quotient of lists are performed individually on each of elements. Checked this for simple examples.

P.S.2) I have also checked that Chop is not the issue.

Comment: Try `Data1[NN_]:=Table[N[dCI[n],50],{n,1,NN}];
Data2[NN_]:=Table[N[Sum[dFO[k] t[k,n],{k,1,n}],50],{n,1,NN}];`

Comment: You have to distinguish between exact numbers and machine numbers. Everything with a decimal point is only an approximation. Therefore the difference is a small number. The quotient is very nearly 1, but the deviation from 1 is smaller than a machine number next to 1 can represent. Read in the help about Precision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, inexact numbers are rounded to six digits for display purposes. The results of your division are `1.` to six digits, but not exactly one:

```
Data1[20]/Data2[20] // FullForm
```

> List[1.0000000000000002`,1.0000000000000007`,0.9999999999999991`,1.000000000000001`,0.9999999999999988`,1.0000000000000049`,1.000000000000015`,0.9999999999999365`,1.0000000000003755`,0.9999999999999385`,1.0000000000006077`,0.9999999999989487`,1.0000000000016644`,0.9999999999949326`,1.0000000000159515`,0.9999999999831284`,1.0000000000278046`,0.99999999994277`,1.0000000002367122`,0.9999999997566881`]